# Maven muti module project same dependneies are overriden with latet version

Tags: java, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.6.1.I have a maven multi module project in which I have a module a and module b.

Module a has jgroups dependency 4.0.10 version.

Module b has jgroups dependency 4.2.10 version.

After I run maven build on top parent maven project which contains module a and b,in the target dependency of jgroups 4.2.10 is only present and not 4.0.10.

How can I get the 4.0.10 dependency in target?

Comment: What sort of packaging are you creating? How will your application manage having two different versions on the classpath? Also you've tagged this question with maven 2 and 3, please remove the one you aren't using.

Comment: @tgdavies i am using Apache Maven 3.6.The packaging i am doing is pom in parent project.The sub project are packaged as bundle.

Comment: So two bundles, each of which should have a different version of jgroups?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Please show your pom file files...Packaging `bundle` means OSGi... have you defined the dependencies in your pom or defined in MANIFEST ?

Comment: Packaging bundle ...Yes is OSGI.I have defined dependencies in pom.xml of project a with jgroups 4.0.10 and for project b with jgroups 4.2.10 for dependencies.